# How to print the values of ParameterGrid?

Tags: scikit-learn, grid

So I have till now something like this:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import ParameterGrid

x1 = np.arange(4, 7, 1).tolist()
x2 = np.arange(0.20, 0.30, 0.05).tolist()
x1 = np.arange(4, 7, 1).tolist()

param_grid = {'param1': x1, 'param2' : x2}

grid = ParameterGrid(param_grid)
```

and I would like to print the values of 'grid'.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could convert the `ParameterGrid` object to a list and then `print()` the list.

```
print(list(grid))
[{'param1': 4, 'param2': 0.2}, {'param1': 4, 'param2': 0.25}, {'param1': 5, 'param2': 0.2}, {'param1': 5, 'param2': 0.25}, {'param1': 6, 'param2': 0.2}, {'param1': 6, 'param2': 0.25}]
```